# Android File IO for binary file

Tags: android, file-io

I want to do file operations for binary file which contains Same type and same size of records. I want to read, write and modify these records also need to jump on records and want to do next, last first, privious operations on records.

In Android, Which IO will be suitable for these requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to Android, use `java.io.RandomAccessFile`.